# Python class instances share the same values

Tags: python

I am experiencing something strange.
I have defined some Python classes, and when I create objects from them, the instances seem to have the same variable values. Can someone please help me debug this?

Here is a minimal example:

```
    from dataclasses import dataclass, field
    
    
    @dataclass
    class Levels:
        level_list: list = field(init=False)
    
        def __post_init__(self):
            self.level_list = []
    
        def add(self, lvl):
            self.level_list.append(lvl)
    
    
    @dataclass
    class Building:
        levels: Levels = field(default=Levels())
```

```
    b = Building()  # instantiate
    b.levels.add("Ground Floor")
    print(b.levels)  # >> Levels(level_list=['Ground Floor'])
    
    c = Building()  # instantiate another one
    c.levels  # >> Levels(level_list=['Ground Floor']) !!!
```

Why doesn't c get its own Levels object?

Comment: `field(default_factory=Levels)`…!

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to make sure I understand why this works:  `default=Levels()` results in the Levels() call being evaluated once the class definition code is executed. In contrast `default_factory=Levels` makes it call Levels() every time a `Building()` is instantiated, right?

Comment: Exactly right, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
field(default=Levels())
```

This literally calls `Levels()` once right here, and uses its resulting value (a `Levels` instance) as the default value for every `Building` instance.

What you want is to make a new `Levels` instance for every `Building` instance, and you do that with the `default_factory` parameter:

```
levels: Levels = field(default_factory=Levels)
```

`default_factory` takes a *callable* and will call it every time a default value is needed.